# How to post a value to a controller function on button click using Ajax and also redirect to new page at the same time?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a button `Next` that changes the page -

```
<a class="disabled" href="step">
   <button class="btn btn-primary launch-btn disabled next">NEXT</button>
</a>
```

Also, when this button is clicked, I have an Ajax function that sends data to a controller function -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.next').click(function() {
    var a = $('#box').data('val');

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>study/CreateData",
       data: a,
       success: function(data)
       {
          console.log(data); 
       },
       error: function()
       {
          console.log("fail");
       } 
     });
  });
});
</script>
```

And I'm using this to receive the value from Ajax -

```
public function CreateData() {
        $data = $this->input->post('data');
        return $data;
    }
```

When the `Next` button hits its controller where it changes to a new page, I'm trying to retrieve the value posted by Ajax to the `CreateData()` function -

```
public function step()
    {
        $data = $this->CreateData();
        if(!empty($data)){
            print_r($data); exit;
        }
        else {
            echo "blank"; exit;
        }
        $this->load->view('step2');
    }
```

However, this keeps echoing `blank`. This obviously means that the `$data` being returned is empty but I'm not sure why. The `success` function in my Ajax script is logging `data`, so it's posting the value to `CreateData()`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript should be something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.next').click(function() {
    var a = $('#box').data('val');

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>study/CreateData",
       data: {my_data: a},
       success: function(data)
       {
          console.log(data); 
       },
       error: function()
       {
          console.log("fail");
       } 
     });
  });
});
</script>
```

Notice the `data` property. I have changed it to an object containing the variable `a`.

Now you should be able to retrieve this in your php function using

```
public function CreateData() {
        $data = $this->input->post('my_data');
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but that didn't work. It still keeps echoing `blank`. I'm wondering if the problem is not with Ajax posting the data but instead the way I'm trying to retrieve the value in the function `step`. I'm guessing that the `$data` variable in `createData()` is getting overwritten with nothing when I call it from the `step` function?

Answer (score 0):

[Adr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3470608/adr)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38044738/3906773) solved part of the problem. In order to actually store and access the data, storing it in the session instead of a variable did the trick -

```
public function CreateData() {
        $data = $this->input->post();
        $this->session->unset_userdata('createData');
        $this->session->set_userdata('createData', $data);
}
```

This prevented the `$data` variable from being overwritten when called the second time.